# ComboBox binding - Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am facing a small problem.  I am binding ComboBox with two properties. IDTypeCodes is a collection which have IDTYPDSC and IDTYPCDE properties. Ome more collection is PCodes which has a property IDTYPECDE.

I want to add all IDTYPCDE in ComboBox but for displaying purpose, i am using IDTYPDSC. but SelectedValue will be

IDTYPECDE and this value should be displayed when i try to open the wiindow again.

```
<ns:GridViewDataColumn>
    <ns:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>                                     
               <DataTemplate> 
                   <ns:ComboBox Margin="8,0" 
                       x:Name = "cmbIDTypeCode" 
                       SelectedValue="{Binding IDTYPECDE,Mode=TwoWay}"
                       Loaded="cmbIDTypeCode_Loaded" /> 
               </DataTemplate> 
    </ns:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate> 
</ns:GridViewDataColumn>
```

.cs file ============================

```
  private void cmbIDTypeCode_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        { 
            cmbIDTypeCode = (NetSolControls.ComboBox)sender; 
            cmbIDTypeCode.ItemsSource = IDTypeCodes; 
            cmbIDTypeCode.DisplayMemberPath = "IDTYPDSC"; 
            cmbIDTypeCode.SelectedValuePath = "IDTYPCDE";            
        }
```

=========================================================================================

I also have tried in this but the problem is still there. Now how can i get the reference of cmbIDTypeCode ? because it is located in DataTemplate of Grid.

if (cmbIDTypeCode == null) cmbIDTypeCode = new NetSolControls.ComboBox(); 
            Binding bindSelectedValue = new Binding("IDTYPECDE"); 
            bindSelectedValue.Source = Controller.DataContext.PROPOSALAPPLICANT[index].PROPOSALAPPLICANTIDDETAIL; 
            Binding bindDisplayMemberPath = new Binding("IDTYPDSC"); 
            bindDisplayMemberPath.Source = IDTypeCodes; 
            Binding bindSelectedValuePath = new Binding("IDTYPCDE"); 
            bindSelectedValuePath.Source = IDTypeCodes; 
            bindDisplayMemberPath.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay; 
            bindSelectedValuePath.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay; 
            bindSelectedValue.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay; 
            cmbIDTypeCode.SetBinding(NetSolControls.ComboBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, bindSelectedValue); 
            cmbIDTypeCode.SetBinding(NetSolControls.ComboBox.SelectedValuePathProperty, bindSelectedValuePath); 
            cmbIDTypeCode.SetBinding(NetSolControls.ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, bindSelectedValue);

================================================================= Have tired in Another way ===========================

object wantedNode = gvIDDetail.FindName("cmbIDTypeCode");returning null. I also tried in this way but still unsuccessfull.

```
                                    ItemsSource ="{Binding IDTypeCodes.IDTYPECODEInfo}"  
                                                 DisplayMemberPath="IDTYPDSC" 
                                                 SelectedValuePath="IDTYPCDE" 
                        SelectedValue="{Binding PropsoalApplicants.PROPOSALAPPLICANTIDDETAILInfo.IDTYPECDE, Mode=TwoWay}" /> 

                                </DataTemplate> 
                            </ns:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate> 
                        </ns:GridViewDataColumn>
```